# Site Collection App Catalog - Install tenant level permission apps

Tags: apps-development, catalog

I have created app catalog for a site collection as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog). I am able to use this catalog to install apps that require normal site level permissions.

I have an app that requires read permission at tenant level:

```
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Read" />
```

This app is added in the site collection app catalog. When I click to install this app it shows message "You can't add this app here." And on clicking "Find out why" it shows:

[image]

I guess apps requiring permissions beyond site collection are not allowed via the site collection catalog. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Are you sure the Scope shouldn't be hxxp://sharepoint/CONTENT/tenant? (had to make http --> hxxp for it to show correctly in here.

Comment: @JussiPalo: Yes, I have both content/tenant and social/tenant in the app. Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

"This is a misleading status message that may indicate the app is already installed. After clicking on the App for the first time, the installation process starts without prompting the user. If you then reopen the App Catalog, you will find that the app status states, “You can’t add this app here”."

Reference: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/sharepoint-apps-you-can-t-add-this-app-here-from-you/ba-p/1303268

"Account used to create App Catalog Site Collection, must be Site Collection Administrators on both the tenant-level App Catalog and the target Site Collection.

Although solutions installed in site collection app catalogs can only be used in these particular site collections, they can potentially access resources from other sites in the tenant"

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog